# Запускается консоль GRUB после установки Debian

Tags: debian, grub, boot

Установил Debian 10 (10.3) на ноутбук с `UEFI/GPT`. Но система не запускается.

Перед этим создал загрузочный образ на USB-накопителе в режиме `ISO` с помощь `Rufus`. Во время установки ситемы создаю раздел `EFI` и шифрую, накрывая `LVM`, оставшиеся место на диске.

Примечание: обнаружил, что установщик предлагает выбрать диск для установки `GRUB` в режиме `MBR/BIOS`, но в моем случае - или всегда в `UEFI` - это не происходит.

Примечание 2: в ноутбуке установлен накопитель NVME

Примечание 3: Команда `ls` в GRUB выводит:`(proc) (hd0) (hd0, gpt2) (hd0, gpt1)`. Все диски за исключением `(proc)` имеют одинаковый размер.

Обновлено: создал флешку в режиме MBR (`BIOS/UEFI`) и переустановил систему. Проблема сохранилась, однако в `(hd0, gp1)` появился каталог `efi` с файлами debian.

Comment: Пробовали ли вы загрузку в рековери? https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319/how-can-i-start-ubuntu-in-safe-mode

Comment: Не запускается. Удерживал и `Shift`, и `Shift+Esc` - ничего, все та же консоль.

Comment: Еще предположение, попробуйте - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204387/debian-not-booting-into-gui

Comment: @DenisE Это тут совсем ни при чём. Тут не графика не грузится, а граб не может систему загрузить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тот же [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084330/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-linux-luks-lvm-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81-uefi) с более подробным описанием и некоторыми - судя по всему, верными - соображениями насчет источника проблемы.

Оказалось, дело действительно в том, что раздел `/boot` зашифрован, и загрузчик попросту не может запустить ядро.

**Решение**: во время разметки диска, помимо раздела `EFI`, нужно создать `/boot`.