# Установка Linux (LUKS, LVM) на компьютер с UEFI

Tags: linux, debian, grub, boot

Имеется ноутбук с `UEFI`. Необходимо установить `Linux` дистрибутив - `Debian` - с полным шифрованием и `LVM`.

Размечаю диск во время установки системы:

```
nvme0n1:
|--nvme0n1p1 (EFI, vfat)
|--nvme0n1p2 (crypto_LUKS):
   |--LVM:
      |--swap
      |--root
      |--home
```

На разделе `EFI` хранятся исключительно файлы `GRUB`:

```
/EFI/debian:
   BOOTX64.CSV
   fbx64.efi
   grub.cfg
   grubx64.efi
   mmx64.efi
   shimx64.efi
```

Получается, как я понимаю, это и есть файлы загрузчика, которые запускаются в первую очередь. Однако запуск самой системы не происходит: все прекращается на консоли `GRUB`.

На команду `boot` загрузчик сообщает, что сперва необходимо указать путь к образу ядра. Но есть проблема: раздел `/boot` не имеет отдельной точки монтирования и содержится в `/`, - `root`. А тот, в свою очередь, зашифрован.

Существуют две гипотезы: нужно отдельно настраивать раздел `/boot` при разметка диска, - исключать из шифрования, - или `GRUB` не может начать расшифровку раздела (кажется, он и не должен это делать, потому как его задача, по моему разумению, - запустить ядро).

Скажите, пожалуйста, как с этим справится - запустить систему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Источник проблемы на самом деле исходит от раздела `/boot`, - его отсутствия, если точнее.

[Расширенный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084084/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-grub-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-debian/1084364#1084364).

Answer (score 0):

Вы в папке /EFI видите inird образы и ядро? И я не вижу. Они зашифрованы. Поэтому должно быть например как-то так:

```
nvme0n1:
|--nvme0n1p1 (EFI, vfat)
|--nvme0n1p2 (boot, ext4)
|--nvme0n1p3 (crypto_LUKS):
   |--LVM:
      |--swap
      |--root
      |--home
```

Соответственно при установке в /boot попадут инитрд образы и ядро(а).